# Meteor: change db.find() from an event

Tags: javascript, templates, events, meteor

I have a template with an <#each>.

```
    <template name="listing">

        {{#each adList}}

            {{> adItemTemplate}}

        {{/each}}

    </template>
```

I'm sending data to the <#each> using this code:

```
    Template.listing.adList = function(){

        return listingDB.find()

    }
```

This gives me a nice list of the articles. However, i have a button that narrows the listing with this.

```
listingDB.find({location:"newyork"})
```

I'm trying to do it with an event but nothing happens:

```
    Template.narrowSearch.events({

        "click .search":function(){

            listingDB.find({location:"newyork"})

        }

    })
```

What am i missing?

thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to bear in mind:

1. Your template will only ever render what the helper function returns, and there's nothing in your code that's going to change what that is.  You're running a completely separate database query in the event handler, the results of which won't go anywhere.
2. In order to have you template helper rerun *reactively* when you change some setting, it needs to depend on a [reactive data source](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivity).

So the upshot of all that is that you should be doing something like:

```
Session.set("query", {});

Template.listing.adList = function() {
    return listingDB.find(query);
}

Template.narrowSearch.events({
    "click .search":function() {
        Session.set(query, {
            location: "newyork"
        });
    }
})
```

Note that a session variable is not the only (or necessarily the correct) way to provide this reactivity - if you want something more private, use a [ReactiveVar](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg).

Answer (score 0):

```
Template.listing.adList = function(){
    var query = Session.get('query') || {};

    return listingDB.find(query);

}

Template.narrowSearch.events({

    "click .search":function(){
        Session.set(query, {location: 'newyork'});

    }

})
```